# Issue with my battle engine

Tags: python

I a bit of a python n00b, and I'm creating a kind of battle scene, and IDLE keeps saying that a simple `else` block. Here is the code.

```
import random

chanceToHitP1 = ([2, 3, 4])
chanceToHitP2 = ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])


playerHP = 30
enemyHP = 40

playerAttackPower1 = 20
#Accuracy for move 1 is 75%
playerAttackPower2 = 10
#Accuracy for move 2 is 100%
playerAttackPower3 = 15
#Accuracy for move 3 is 90%

enemyAttackPower1 = 20
#Accuracy for move 1 is 75%
enemyAttackPower2 = 10
#Accuracy for move 2 is 100%
enemyAttackPower3 = 15
#Accuracy for move 3 is 90%


def player_turn():
    print " what move would you like to make?"
    moveMade = input()
    # Move 1
    if moveMade == 1:
        accuracyChance = random.choice ([2, 3, 4, 1])
        if accuracyChance in chanceToHitP1:
            print "You hit!"
            enemyHP = (enemyHP - playerAttackPower1                                                                      
        else:
            print "your attack missed.."

# Move 2       
elif moveMade == 2:
print "Your attack hit!"
enemyHP = (enemyHP - playerAttackPower2)

# Move 3
elif moveMade == 3:
accuracyChance = random.choice ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1])
if accuracyChance in chanceToHitP2:
    print "You hit!"
    enemyHP = (enemyHP - playerAttackPower3) 
else: print "You missed" [This is where it has an error]
player_turn()
```

This isn't complete, and the `player_turn()` will be in a loop until someone has got 0 ore less HP. When I run it, IDLE will highlight the `else` that I pointed out. I don't know why, and I would really appreciate some help... Thank you!

Comment: Is this the right indentation ??

Comment: _"IDLE keeps saying that a simple else block"_. Sorry, what is IDLE saying about the simple else block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enemyHP = (enemyHP - playerAttackPower1
```

You've got a mismatched parenthesis here. Add a right one, or delete the left one.

```
enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAttackPower1
```

Or

```
enemyHP = (enemyHP - playerAttackPower1)
```